# Python: Invalid syntax (can't find the reason)

Tags: python, formatting, syntax-error

There's an Invalid Syntax in the 5th line - in bold - I can't find the reason behind it! I'd appreciate your help.

filter_entry = input("Would you like to filter the data by month, day, both or not at all? ").lower()

while filter_entry not in (["month", "day", "both", "not at all"]):

print("INVALID ENTRY! Please enter one of these filters (month, day, both or not at all) ")

filter_entry = str(input("Would you like to filter the data by month, day, both or not at all? ").lower()

**months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June"]**

if filter_entry == "month" or filter_entry == "both":

```
  month = str(input("Which month - January, February, March, April, May or June? ")).title()
```

while month not in months:

```
 print("INVALID ENTRY! please enter one month of the first six months. ")
     month = str(input("Which month - January, February, March, April, May or June? ")).title()
```

else:
month = "all"

Comment: Missing `)` on the previous line. (It's almost always that.)

Comment: And note that you don't need to `str()` from `input()`. Assuming you're on Python 3, `input()` will give you a string automatically. (And if you're on Python 2—which you definitely shouldn't be 11 days from 2021—you should be using `raw_input()`, which also returns a string.)

Comment: Also it would help to put the whole code block in code formatting. It’s hard to read this way.

Comment: The downvote wasn’t mine, but I do think this question belongs in the Code Review stack rather than this one, as it’s a question about your specific program rather than about a general programming concept. This type of question would probably get a better reception there.

Comment: @bob, I don't think so. There is a clear error and error message. As far as I know, [codereview.se] [is for improving _working_ code](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour): "Don't ask about... How to fix compile-time errors, runtime errors, or incorrect results". This is closer to being on-topic here, but it's effectively a typo.

Comment: I can see that. Do we allow “find my bug” questions here? In this case it was helpful for OP, which is good, but it seems unlikely to be very helpful for future users (except as a cautionary tale about mismatched parentheses :)), which is an important feature  of good questions on SO as I understand it. That was the rational behind my comment. But I’m not super familiar with Code Review, so I may have misspoken there.

Comment: Well this isn't really "find my bug". OP provided code, an error message (though a full traceback would have been better), and a line. It was sufficient to identify the problem and answer it in a comment. But since it's effectively a typo it will be closed. If it had been on-topic I'd have written an answer, not a comment.

Answer (score 0):

The 'Invalid Syntax' is in the line before the bold line where there is a missing ')' in the following line:

```
filter_entry = str(input("Would you like to filter the data by month, day, both or not at all? ").lower()
```

The below is a corrected version.

```
filter_entry = str(input("Would you like to filter the data by month, day, both or not at all? ")).lower()
```